# How to fix "Component is defined but never used" for eslint in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

This is the config i have for eslint in `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
 {
        "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "commonjs": true,
            "es6": true
        },
        "extends": "eslint:recommended",
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 6,
            "ecmaFeatures": {
                "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
                "jsx": true
            },
            "sourceType": "module"
        },
        "plugins": [
            "react"
        ],
        "rules": {
            "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",
            "react/jsx-uses-vars": ["error"],
            "indent": 0,
            "linebreak-style": [
                "error",
                "windows"
            ],
            "quotes": [
                "error",
                "single"
            ],
            "semi": [
                "error",
                "always"
            ]
        },
        "settings": {
        "react": {
          "pragma": "React",
          "version": "15.0"
        }
      }
    }
```

This is the `app.jsx` from the react workspace below:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class App extends React.Component {
      render () {
        return(
          <h1>Hello Newbies</h1>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

I am getting error from eslint `'Component' is defined but never used.` I can not fix this by doing anything so far but digging the web. How can i fix this error? Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
class App extends Component {
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:**
You don't need to import {Component} since you extends React.component and React is already imported.

**Option 2:**
You can extend your App with Component instead of React.Component

Comment: Adding on to the above answers you may have:

`import React, {Component} from 'react'`
 but never used Component as in like this in your file:
 `class App extends Component`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "import React, { Component } from 'react';" this line and warning will be resolved as this will be not used in functional based Components.

Comment: This may resolve the warning, but it will cause even more issues because it's also removing the `React` variable which is being used in this script. If they were to make this change, instead of there just being a warning, the code wouldn't run at all.